# Replace values after a specific event by group in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In the `data.table` below for each group variable `id`, the base value for `event` column is either 1 or -1. At times, a new event is generated and replaces these base values. The new event values can be any numeric value except 1 or -1. I want to propagate the event value for each group till the time the next new event is encountered.

```
temp_dt = structure(list(date = structure(c(18263L, 18264L, 18267L, 18268L, 
18269L, 18270L, 18271L, 18274L, 18275L, 18276L, 18277L, 18278L, 
18282L, 18283L, 18284L, 18285L, 18288L, 18289L, 18290L, 18291L, 
18292L, 18295L, 18296L, 18297L, 18298L, 18299L, 18302L, 18303L, 
18304L, 18305L, 18306L, 18310L, 18311L, 18312L, 18313L, 18316L, 
18317L, 18318L, 18319L, 18320L, 18323L, 18324L, 18325L, 18326L, 
18327L, 18330L, 18331L, 18332L, 18333L, 18334L, 18337L, 18338L, 
18339L, 18340L, 18341L, 18344L, 18345L, 18346L, 18347L, 18348L
), class = c("IDate", "Date")), id = c(43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 
45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 
45L, 45L, 45L), event = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
> head(temp_dt, 20)
          date id event
 1: 2020-01-02 43    -1
 2: 2020-01-03 43    -1
 3: 2020-01-06 43    -1
 4: 2020-01-07 43    -1
 5: 2020-01-08 43    -1
 6: 2020-01-09 43    -1
 7: 2020-01-10 43    -1
 8: 2020-01-13 43    -1
 9: 2020-01-14 44     1
10: 2020-01-15 44     1
11: 2020-01-16 44     1
12: 2020-01-17 44     1
13: 2020-01-21 44     1
14: 2020-01-22 44     1
15: 2020-01-23 44    -4
16: 2020-01-24 44     1
17: 2020-01-27 44     1
18: 2020-01-28 44     1
19: 2020-01-29 44     1
20: 2020-01-30 44     1
```

Here is the desired result and the expected output is in `signal` column

```
          date id event signal
 1: 2020-01-02 43    -1     -1
 2: 2020-01-03 43    -1     -1
 3: 2020-01-06 43    -1     -1
 4: 2020-01-07 43    -1     -1
 5: 2020-01-08 43    -1     -1
 6: 2020-01-09 43    -1     -1
 7: 2020-01-10 43    -1     -1
 8: 2020-01-13 43    -1     -1
 9: 2020-01-14 44     1      1
10: 2020-01-15 44     1      1
11: 2020-01-16 44     1      1
12: 2020-01-17 44     1      1
13: 2020-01-21 44     1      1
14: 2020-01-22 44     1      1
15: 2020-01-23 44    -4     -4
16: 2020-01-24 44     1     -4
17: 2020-01-27 44     1     -4
18: 2020-01-28 44     1     -4
19: 2020-01-29 44     1     -4
20: 2020-01-30 44     1     -4
21: 2020-01-31 44     1     -4
22: 2020-02-03 44    -2     -2
23: 2020-02-04 44     1     -2
24: 2020-02-05 44     1     -2
25: 2020-02-06 44     1     -2
26: 2020-02-07 44     1     -2
27: 2020-02-10 44     1     -2
28: 2020-02-11 44     1     -2
29: 2020-02-12 44     1     -2
30: 2020-02-13 44     1     -2
31: 2020-02-14 44     1     -2
32: 2020-02-18 44     1     -2
33: 2020-02-19 44     1     -2
34: 2020-02-20 44     1     -2
35: 2020-02-21 44     1     -2
36: 2020-02-24 44     1     -2
37: 2020-02-25 44     1     -2
38: 2020-02-26 45    -1     -1
39: 2020-02-27 45    -2     -2
40: 2020-02-28 45    -1     -2
41: 2020-03-02 45    -1     -2
42: 2020-03-03 45    -1     -2
43: 2020-03-04 45    -1     -2
44: 2020-03-05 45    -1     -2
45: 2020-03-06 45    -1     -2
46: 2020-03-09 45    -1     -2
47: 2020-03-10 45    -1     -2
48: 2020-03-11 45    -1     -2
49: 2020-03-12 45    -1     -2
50: 2020-03-13 45    -1     -2
51: 2020-03-16 45    -1     -2
52: 2020-03-17 45    -1     -2
53: 2020-03-18 45     4      4
54: 2020-03-19 45    -1      4
55: 2020-03-20 45    -1      4
56: 2020-03-23 45    -1      4
57: 2020-03-24 45    -1      4
58: 2020-03-25 45    -1      4
59: 2020-03-26 45    -1      4
60: 2020-03-27 45    -1      4
          date id event signal
```

My solution for this problem is somehow not working as expected. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
temp_dt[, signal:= ifelse(abs(event) == 1 & shift(abs(event)) != 1, shift(event), event) , by = id]

          date id event signal
 1: 2020-01-02 43    -1     NA
 2: 2020-01-03 43    -1     -1
 3: 2020-01-06 43    -1     -1
 4: 2020-01-07 43    -1     -1
 5: 2020-01-08 43    -1     -1
 6: 2020-01-09 43    -1     -1
 7: 2020-01-10 43    -1     -1
 8: 2020-01-13 43    -1     -1
 9: 2020-01-14 44     1     NA
10: 2020-01-15 44     1      1
11: 2020-01-16 44     1      1
12: 2020-01-17 44     1      1
13: 2020-01-21 44     1      1
14: 2020-01-22 44     1      1
15: 2020-01-23 44    -4     -4
16: 2020-01-24 44     1     -4
17: 2020-01-27 44     1      1
18: 2020-01-28 44     1      1
```

Here is another attempt

```
temp_dt[, signal := {
  rn <- 1:.N
  i2 <- which(abs(event) != 1)
  fcase(
    rn %inrange% .(i2 + 1, i2 + 3), event,
    rn %in% i2, event
  )}, by = id]
```

Here is one more try but it has problems too -

```
temp_dt[, signal := cummax(abs(event)), by = id]
```

Otherwise, a simple `data.table` solution **without** using `joins` will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the cumulative sum of whether `event` is -1 or 1 to the group by and take the first element of `event` for each group:

```
temp_dt[, signal := event[1], .(id, grp = cumsum(!(event %in% c(-1, 1))))]
```

Alternatively,

```
temp_dt[, signal := event[1], .(id, grp = cumsum(abs(event) - 1))]
```

Comment: Thanks, jblood. This is the simplest one-line solution.

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `data.table`.

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(emp_dt)[, signal := fifelse(event != shift(event), event, NA_real_), by = id]
emp_dt[, signal := fifelse(abs(event) != 1, signal, NA_real_), by = id]
emp_dt[, signal := fifelse(rowidv(event) == 1, event, signal), by = id]
setnafill(emp_dt, cols = "signal", type = "locf")
emp_dt
#>           date id event signal
#>  1: 2020-01-02 43    -1     -1
#>  2: 2020-01-03 43    -1     -1
#>  3: 2020-01-06 43    -1     -1
#>  4: 2020-01-07 43    -1     -1
#>  5: 2020-01-08 43    -1     -1
#>  6: 2020-01-09 43    -1     -1
#>  7: 2020-01-10 43    -1     -1
#>  8: 2020-01-13 43    -1     -1
#>  9: 2020-01-14 44     1      1
#> 10: 2020-01-15 44     1      1
#> 11: 2020-01-16 44     1      1
#> 12: 2020-01-17 44     1      1
#> 13: 2020-01-21 44     1      1
#> 14: 2020-01-22 44     1      1
#> 15: 2020-01-23 44    -4     -4
#> 16: 2020-01-24 44     1     -4
#> 17: 2020-01-27 44     1     -4
#> 18: 2020-01-28 44     1     -4
#> 19: 2020-01-29 44     1     -4
#> 20: 2020-01-30 44     1     -4
#> 21: 2020-01-31 44     1     -4
#> 22: 2020-02-03 44    -2     -2
#> 23: 2020-02-04 44     1     -2
#> 24: 2020-02-05 44     1     -2
#> 25: 2020-02-06 44     1     -2
#> 26: 2020-02-07 44     1     -2
#> 27: 2020-02-10 44     1     -2
#> 28: 2020-02-11 44     1     -2
#> 29: 2020-02-12 44     1     -2
#> 30: 2020-02-13 44     1     -2
#> 31: 2020-02-14 44     1     -2
#> 32: 2020-02-18 44     1     -2
#> 33: 2020-02-19 44     1     -2
#> 34: 2020-02-20 44     1     -2
#> 35: 2020-02-21 44     1     -2
#> 36: 2020-02-24 44     1     -2
#> 37: 2020-02-25 44     1     -2
#> 38: 2020-02-26 45    -1     -1
#> 39: 2020-02-27 45    -2     -2
#> 40: 2020-02-28 45    -1     -2
#> 41: 2020-03-02 45    -1     -2
#> 42: 2020-03-03 45    -1     -2
#> 43: 2020-03-04 45    -1     -2
#> 44: 2020-03-05 45    -1     -2
#> 45: 2020-03-06 45    -1     -2
#> 46: 2020-03-09 45    -1     -2
#> 47: 2020-03-10 45    -1     -2
#> 48: 2020-03-11 45    -1     -2
#> 49: 2020-03-12 45    -1     -2
#> 50: 2020-03-13 45    -1     -2
#> 51: 2020-03-16 45    -1     -2
#> 52: 2020-03-17 45    -1     -2
#> 53: 2020-03-18 45     4      4
#> 54: 2020-03-19 45    -1      4
#> 55: 2020-03-20 45    -1      4
#> 56: 2020-03-23 45    -1      4
#> 57: 2020-03-24 45    -1      4
#> 58: 2020-03-25 45    -1      4
#> 59: 2020-03-26 45    -1      4
#> 60: 2020-03-27 45    -1      4
#>           date id event signal
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Wow, this is really simple solution. Thanks, NicChr.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it WITHOUT data.table in base R. Hopefully someone gives you the join data.table efficient solution soon!

```
# split by group
L <- split(temp_dt, temp_dt[,id])
for(i in 1:length(L)){
  # ensure date is ordered oldest to newest
  L[[i]] <- L[[i]][order(date)]
  # prepare to loop through all rows except the last one
  n <- nrow(L[[i]])-1
  for(j in 1:n){
    # if current row is not default and next row is default
    if(abs(L[[i]][j, event]) != 1 & abs(L[[i]][j + 1, event]) == 1){
      # carry not default forward
      L[[i]][j + 1, "event"] = L[[i]][j, event]
    }
  }
}
# turns lists of data.tables into one data.table
new_signal <- rbindlist(L)
# rename the event column to "signal"
colnames(new_signal) <- c("date","id","signal")
# merge them together for your answer
temp_dt <- merge(temp_dt, new_signal)
```